# How to implement the mount with golang

Tags: linux, go

Can I use go to implement the mount function in Linux? Mount a path transferred from the foreground to a local path?such as

```
add_iptables "${shared_file_path}"

if [[ "x$domain" == "xnoDomain" ]]
then
    expect > /dev/null 2>&1 <<EOF
    set timeout 1
    //
    spawn /usr/bin/mount -t cifs -o nodev,nosuid,noexec,username=${user_name} ${shared_file_path} ${local_path}
    expect {
        "Passwor*:"            {send "${local_pws}\n"}
    }
    expect eof
    catch wait result
    exit [lindex \$result 3]
EOF
else
    expect > /dev/null 2>&1 <<EOF
    set timeout 1
    spawn /usr/bin/mount -t cifs -o nodev,nosuid,noexec,domain=${domain},username=${user_name} ${shared_file_path} ${local_path}
    expect {
        "Passwor*:"            {send "${local_pws}\n"}
    }
    expect eof
    catch wait result
    exit [lindex \$result 3]
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Go to wrap a system call to pretty much anything you want.

For instance, in [`nanobox-io/nanobox` with `util/provider/dockermachine_mount_windows.go`](https://github.com/nanobox-io/nanobox/blob/c90ca1e72c19edc9225dc949f1ab44185b9c98a6/util/provider/dockermachine_mount_windows.go#L47-L87) (extract of a larger function):

```golang
    // ensure cifs/samba utilities are installed
    cmd = []string{"sh", "-c", setupCifsUtilsScript()}
    if b, err := Run(cmd); err != nil {
        lumber.Debug("cifs output: %s", b)
        return fmt.Errorf("cifs:%s", err.Error())
    }

    // mount!
    // mount -t cifs -o sec=ntlmssp,username=USER,password=PASSWORD,uid=1000,gid=1000 //192.168.99.1/<path to app> /<vm location>
    source := fmt.Sprintf("//192.168.99.1/nanobox-%s", appID)
    // mfsymlinks,
    config, _ := models.LoadConfig()
    additionalOptions := config.NetfsMountOpts

    // since the mount command inserts the user into the command string with
    // single quotes, we need to escape any single quotes from the real
    // username. As the command will be running in bash, the actual escape
    // sequence is a bit tricky. Each ' will be replaced with '"'"'.
    escapedUser := strings.Replace(user, "'", "'\"'\"'", -1)

    opts := fmt.Sprintf("nodev,sec=ntlmssp,user='%s',password='%s',uid=1000,gid=1000", escapedUser, pass)
    if additionalOptions != "" {
        opts = fmt.Sprintf("%s,%s", additionalOptions, opts)
    }

    cmd = []string{
        "sudo",
        "/bin/mount",
        "-t",
        "cifs",
        "-o",
        opts,
        source,
        host,
    }

    lumber.Debug("cifs mount cmd: %v", cmd)
    if b, err := Run(cmd); err != nil {
        lumber.Debug("mount output: %s", b)
        return fmt.Errorf("mount: output: %s err:%s", b, err.Error())
    }
```